# ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot - prevent whiskers from extending to extremes

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggthemes

Does someone know how to prevent the "whiskers" in `ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot` to be drawn up to the extreme values? 
I tried changing the `outlier` and `whisker` arguments to no avail.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Whisker extend to 1.5xIQR as usual:
[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_tufteboxplot()
```

"Whisker" extend to extreme value
[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: To my opinion, your whiskers looks similar in both functions. In `geom_boxplot`, you can pass the argument `coef` to set the multiplier of the IQR. is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: @dc37  `virginica`'s lower whisker extends to the outlier (the actual data extreme) and not the default minimum value (i.e. lower quartile - 1.5*IQR). I am very happy with the `geom_boxplot`s, so don't need to change that.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, indeed it is different for virginica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workable solution by changing the stat to "boxplot". Here's a reprex (the last example shows how to hide outliers, although the axis range will still consider them; the work-around for that is more involved):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot(stat = "boxplot")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot(stat = "boxplot", outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I don't see a flaw in the axis not adjusting to the outliers not shown - the data is still there! so that is not unintended behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, now that I've played with it a bit more, merely hiding the outliers and not adjusting the axis range is the desired behavior. In my case, I had extreme outliers (akin to, for example, setting some sepal lengths in the iris data set to values in the 1000s) that I wanted to work around, and solved by manually calculating the values to use for the box plots to make sure values outside of 1.5 * IQR were ignored when plotting.